# Integrating Firebase Crashlytics with react native app - stuck in verification

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I am trying to integrate Firebase Crashlytics with react native app. Firebase integration done. Already using firebase service for push notification. It's fine. I'm using cocoapods and added this pods.

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
```

updated the pod using `pod update`.

I'm not using "use_frameworks!" inside pod because of some reasons.

After all, I built my app to reacl device in both debug mode and release mode. But it is not redirecting firebase console to crashlytics dashboard.

Moreover I have imported react-native-firebase and added these lines in main home page,

```
firebase.crashlytics().log('Test Message!');
firebase.crashlytics().recordError(37, "Test Error");
```

But firebase console stuck in the following page itself,

[image: Firebase Console]

I have verified the app package name and plist file. all are proper with this firebase account.

None of the workarounds are helping. Please suggest some directions to enable crashlytics. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you finished all the step of integrating react-native-firebase Crashlytics https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/crashlytics/ios

Comment: Yes, I have done all the steps. Added the pod files. Updated pod. Added crashlytics runscript.

Comment: The problem solved. Actually it's our fault. Someone changed the GoogleService-Info.plist for some testing purposes. It was using other project 's .plist file. I corrected it. It listened to our app request immediately.